# how to add features in angular-meteor (using angular2)

Tags: angular, angular-meteor

I have just gone through tutorial of angular-meteor (socially) and angular 2 (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). In the angular2 guide, they have mentioned how to create submodules (features) and then how it can be easily imported into the app.module.ts. But the issue here is that in meteor-app there is no such app.module.ts and instead they have app.main.ts and in it there is the bootstrap class which tells the entry point in the app. It takes only a component and providers.
Please tell me how can we add submodules (features) in the angular-meteor.

Comment: I changed the tag from `angular-material` to `angular-meteor`. Hope that's okay.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: i tried to add app.module.ts (as mentioned in the tutorial of angular2) but it is throwing the error that NgModule is not there.